# Solve a Matrix for unknows in Python / Numpy / Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scientific-computing, finite-element-analysis

I need to solve this system of matrices for the unkowns `u4`,`f1`,`f2`,`f3`,`f5` and `f6` for a particular `FEA` problem. I have generated the matrix containing the numbers with my input and need to solve it for these knowns.

- The code should act as follows:

  `0 + 0 + 0 + 150*1000*u4 + 0 + 0 = −1732`

therefore, `u4=-0.01154`

- so the other unknowns can be found out as follows:

  `0 + 0 + 0 + (43:4)(−0:0115) 1000 + 0 + 0 = f1`

therefore `f1=-500` 
and so on....

I am a beginner and familiar with the basics of numpy and python OOP. Please help me set up a code for this.

[image: The matrices to be solved]

Answer (score 1):

```
In [0]: import numpy as np    

In [1]: A = np.random.rand(6,6)

In [2]: a4 = A[3,:]

In [3]: u4 = -1732/a4[3]

In [4]: f = a4*u4

In [5]: f
Out[5]: 
array([ -246.6101995 ,  -589.6732277 ,  -574.67690895, -1732.        ,
       -2592.99948033, -2383.52077134])
```

Replace `A` or atleast the fourth column `a4` by your data...

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I need the code to determine the sequence and operators automatically. The code will be reused and the unknowns might be u2 and f5 or any other combination for different cases. The user has to only enter the 3 matrices and the unknowns should be calculated by the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
from __future__ import division
from numpy import asarray as ar,sum as sums

A = ar([[25,-43.3,-25,43.3,0,0],
        [-43.3,75,43.3,-75,0,0],
        [-25,43.3,50,0,-25,-43.3],
        [43.3,-75,0,150,-43.3,-75],
        [0,0,-25,-43.3,25,43.3],
        [0,0,-43.3,-75,43.3,75]])*1e3
u4 = -0.01154
B = ar([0,0,0,u4,0,0])
F = sums(A*B,axis=1)
```

So you will have:

```
>>> F
array([ -499.682,   865.5  ,     0.   , -1731.   ,   499.682,   865.5  ])
```